# How to ignore some invalid lines when using triggers to check input in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
create table Users (
    ID char(10) not null primary key,
    Name nvarchar(30),
    Gender nvarchar(10),
);
```

***Gender*** contains only 1 of 2 values that is male or female.
Suppose I will insert multiple lines at the same time to the ***Users*** table. I wrote a ***trigger function*** to check if the ***gender*** variable is valid with using ***cursor*** variable, otherwise the function will ignore the current line and check the remaining lines. But my teacher said that my method is not good because it takes too much time, is there a better way to solve this problem??? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: SQL is optimized to work in sets, that is multiple rows, at the same time. A cursor is just breaking that optimized process by forcing it to work in a 1 by 1 basis. This is why your teacher said that's not a good approach. It gets the work done but not it a performant way. Please post your trigger code so it's easier to post a set-based answer. Also, you can add a `CHECK` constraint to the table that only allows certain values for a column (without a trigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need check constraint:

```
alter table Users 
add constraint ck_gender
check (Gender in ('MALE', 'FEMALE'));
```

Here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6255ac11c89c60f949d9eb5b940cc9ee)

Maybe something like this will be for you:

```
CREATE Trigger tr_gender_check on Users AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT Gender
           from inserted AS i 
           WHERE i.Gender not in ('MALE', 'FEMALE')
          )
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('A Gender entered is not "MALE" or FEMALE so the insert was not made', 16, 1);
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
       RETURN 
end;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b063ba59e19d817117785697ff2d0d09) for that.

Comment: No, I know this way, but my teacher want to use trigger to solve this

Comment: Ok, then show us the trigger as @EzLo asked. I now see he also mentioned this constraint I wrote. I will remove my answer after some time. Cheers.

Comment: i am learning how to use trigger, the above example just my's short question.

Comment: @ManhCuong . . . Your teacher is wrong to use this as an example.  You should be given an example where a trigger is appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what did teacher used as example ? Oh, you are talking about the whole question as example, where check constraint is just enough and there is no need for trigger ?

Comment: @VBoka . . . Exactly.  At the very least, it should be presented as "This can be done using a check constraint.  For this exercise, though, we are going to use a trigger."  There are better examples for triggers, such as archiving deleted rows or maintaining a count or total sum in a summary table.

Comment: I agree 100%. I also believe this one that I wrote for here will do the job she needs :)